# How can I change the text of a texbox in every second?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a texbox and I want to change it's content every second in Windows Phone 7.. For example I have an int list and I want to show it's first value.. then 1 second later the second value.

Comment: You could use a timer i think?

Comment: It's OK but I don't really know how does it works :S

Comment: Search for windows phone timer APIs. I am not sure the regular C# framework API does the work.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work on WP7 :/

Comment: Care to show the code what have you tried so far?

Comment: 'for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length-1; i++)
{
   numbers[i] = i + 1;
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
   btnumber.Content = numbers[i];
}'
Here is the code. It works on console application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DispatcherTimer is what you're looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Create a new instance of DispatcherTimer, set it to tick every second, and update the textbox in the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here.

http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Implement_Timer_control_in_Windows_Phone

Sample code taken from there:

```
   DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.1)};
   // Constructor
   public MainPage()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       this.timer.Tick+=new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
   }
   private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       output.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
         DispatcherTimer timer;

         private int _seconds;
         public int Seconds
        {
        get 
        { 
           return _seconds;
        }
        set 
        {
           _seconds= value;
           OnPropertyChanged("Seconds");
        }
        }
// Here implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged interface and ctor


    }
```

And in your XAML code use as DataContext

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Seconds}" />
```

Now in your ViewModel just use timer with event Tick and set Seconds to new value that you need to show.